# Why is the exterior shell of this GeoJSON invalid?

Tags: geojson, mongodb

I got some data from Zillow's neighborhood database as shapefiles and converted them to GeoJSON.  However, some of the objects appear to be malformed when inserting them into MongoDb.  Is there anything obvious incorrect with this object?  If not, I'll post to a mongodb group.

I get the mongodb error `Exterior shell of polygon is invalid`

Here is the GeoJSON that validates on http://geojsonlint.com

```
{ "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -118.446969222686, 34.0469016326594 ], [ -118.434190835956, 34.0504320311002 ], [ -118.430613269546, 34.0514987186012 ], [ -118.423933835946, 34.0574851170443 ], [ -118.423199406258, 34.0549809139169 ], [ -118.422660125007, 34.0533079256341 ], [ -118.421636562507, 34.0524724295396 ], [ -118.421512675788, 34.0512202381322 ], [ -118.41717327344, 34.046211074065 ], [ -118.416411648439, 34.0466005350029 ], [ -118.412196886716, 34.0489869060989 ], [ -118.409930683589, 34.0502700193813 ], [ -118.406049503898, 34.0526248670397 ], [ -118.405972386711, 34.0526120701647 ], [ -118.405962628898, 34.0526126092272 ], [ -118.405960624992, 34.0526101170397 ], [ -118.405959847648, 34.0526091482897 ], [ -118.405959847648, 34.0526099881335 ], [ -118.405960624992, 34.0526101170397 ], [ -118.405962624992, 34.0526126092272 ], [ -118.405668488273, 34.0526288904772 ], [ -118.405687144523, 34.0526748201648 ], [ -118.406090394523, 34.0535528201656 ], [ -118.405981945304, 34.0540129959473 ], [ -118.405474109366, 34.0542725857913 ], [ -118.40546691796, 34.0549122811044 ], [ -118.405903062492, 34.0549061678231 ], [ -118.405825968742, 34.0556394139175 ], [ -118.405820851554, 34.0571164373564 ], [ -118.399104050767, 34.0571106834502 ], [ -118.39054288279, 34.0571204920439 ], [ -118.38356623044, 34.0570572772001 ], [ -118.383860707003, 34.0544064764164 ], [ -118.384332789034, 34.0504714412565 ], [ -118.385436363254, 34.0487181834424 ], [ -118.389399999977, 34.0347272732731 ], [ -118.391367691385, 34.0301953865501 ], [ -118.391625523416, 34.0300484412375 ], [ -118.392837789042, 34.0295663865495 ], [ -118.393894082012, 34.0291868552992 ], [ -118.397096902327, 34.0289949412365 ], [ -118.399457230455, 34.029248132643 ], [ -118.404499855459, 34.0296909529559 ], [ -118.407776429681, 34.030082620925 ], [ -118.411082187497, 34.0307397263944 ], [ -118.415095054688, 34.031983468583 ], [ -118.418410257816, 34.0320081951455 ], [ -118.422025265632, 34.0318939295204 ], [ -118.426063460948, 34.0318955701454 ], [ -118.429185390639, 34.0317586248328 ], [ -118.432878500017, 34.0313464529574 ], [ -118.433469000018, 34.0314239021762 ], [ -118.436109089864, 34.0337636365534 ], [ -118.43832727346, 34.0371181795253 ], [ -118.446969222686, 34.0469016326594 ] ] ] }
```

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB does not accept duplicate entries. So I guess you'll have to check and remove if there are any. I was getting the same error and removing the duplicate entries solved it for me.